# Questions on positivity of quadratic form with orthogonal constraints

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratics, quadratic-forms

I'm reading a book and the book gives the following lemma without proof. (The lemma is in the solution to question 2.10 part b in the book of convex optimization by Boyd. The lemma is mentioned on page 9 in the solution manual.)

Suppose

- $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix
- $v$, $g \in R^n$ and $g^T v = 0$

Then $v^TAv \geq 0$ if $\ \exists \ \lambda \in R$, such that $A+\lambda gg^T$ is semipositive definite.

I don't know how to prove this lemma and wish someone could help me!

Comment: This makes little sense. In the line "Then.....such that" there is no occurrence of $v$

Comment: Sorry, the wording of the last statement in the conclusion confuses me, could you check if there is a typo? Is it a statement on semi-positivity of a matrix or are contractions with vectors missing?

Comment: Might help to name the book as well.

Comment: @secavara, yes, it means semi-positive definite. I've also add where the lemma is from.

Comment: @WillJagy, just added the sources. Search "solution manual convex optimization boyd" and you'll find the book.

Comment: There's a typo in the question. It should be $g^Tv=0$ (according to the book and to the fact that $vg^T$ is a matrix).

Comment: @A.P., sorry for the typo and just corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By linearity we have
$$
v^T\left(A + \lambda gg^T\right)v = v^TAv + \lambda (g^Tv)^T g^Tv = v^TAv
$$
thus $v^TAv \geq 0$ if and only if $v^T\left(A + \lambda gg^T\right)v \geq 0$.

To understand why this is reasonable, note that the condition $g^Tv = 0$ means that $g$ is orthogonal to $v$ and that the matrix $gg^T$ represents the orthogonal projection along the line spanned by $g$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The proof is clear here! Meanwhile, I don't quite understand why we want to bring gg^T in here. It seems that we just throw something orthogonal in here, but why?